# How to display API data from url with jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, url, datatables

I'm setting up a "statistic" page for my FiveM's server website, and I need help about how to display data with Jquery Datatables

I don't know anything about API, so i tried few things with PHP, but nothing really usefull :/

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test-astos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- data -->
        </tbody>
    </table>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
      $('#table_id').DataTable({
        $.ajax({
          url : 'https://api.top-serveurs.net/v1/servers/SC4VCSEUS3/players-ranking',
          type : 'GET',
          dataType : 'json',
             success : function(json, statut){ // code_html contient le HTML renvoyé
             }
        });
      });
    });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to display those data (https://api.top-serveurs.net/v1/servers/SC4VCSEUS3/players-ranking) with Jquery datatables.

Thanks :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First You forget to use jQuery CDN see in the example. and use like this.

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Votes</th>
            <th>Player Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- data -->
    </tbody>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {

    $.ajax({
        url : 'https://api.top-serveurs.net/v1/servers/SC4VCSEUS3/players-ranking',
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            bindtoDatatable(data.players);
        }
    });



});

function bindtoDatatable(data) {
        var table = $('#table_id').dataTable({
            "bAutoWidth" : false,
            "aaData" : data,
            "columns" : [ {
                "data" : "votes"
            }, {
                "data" : "playername"
            } ]
        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! i thought it was harder, thanks a lot!

Comment: While this works, this approach is suboptimal - you shall not use external ajax-call to populate your table, there is a native `ajax` option for that purpose - it gives you better performance (for dynamic app, above method will require destroy/re-create your DataTable, or purge/re-populate its contets) and integration with the rest of DataTables API methods.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov  can you write a solution for it for native ajax , becasue returning data is not in a format for native ajax